# Java Error Handling

Tags: java, exception

Grade Average program here; can't figure out how to handle input such as chars and strings; Tried trycatch and while/if (!input.hasNextInt/Double). Can't figure out.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeAvgMinMax {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double largest = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double smallest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double sum = 0;

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                do {

                    System.out.println("How many grades would you like to enter?");

                    int num = input.nextInt();

                    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {

                        System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");

                        double grade = input.nextDouble();

                        while (!input.hasNextInt() || !input.hasNextDouble()) {
                            System.out.println("Not a number!");
                        }

                        while (grade < 0) {

                            System.out.println("Grade cannot be negative, please retry");
                            System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");

                            grade = input.nextDouble();
                        }

                        while (grade > 100) {

                            System.out.println("Grade cannot be over 100, please retry");
                            System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");

                            grade = input.nextDouble();
                        }

                        if (grade > largest) {
                            largest = grade;    
                        }

                        if (grade < smallest) {
                            smallest = grade;
                        }

                            sum = sum + grade;

                   }

        double average = sum/num;
        DecimalFormat df = new
        DecimalFormat ("#.##");

        System.out.println("AVG: " + df.format(average));
        System.out.println("MAX: " + df.format(largest));
        System.out.println("MIN: " + df.format(smallest));

        System.out.println("Would you like to run this program again? (Y/N)");
        } while ("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(input.next().trim()));

                input.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Can't figure out what?!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this entire wrong.

```
System.out.println("Enter Grade: ");
double grade = input.nextDouble();
while (!input.hasNextInt() || !input.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.println("Not a number!");
}
```

The `hasNextDouble()` javadoc says:

> Returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as a double value using the `nextDouble()` method. The scanner does not advance past any input.

You're while loop will run forever if `hasNextDouble()` returns false, because nothing changes.

You must call `hasNextDouble()` **before** calling [`nextDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()). That way `nextDouble()` will never fail and you don't have to catch exceptions.

But, when `hasNextDouble()` returns false, you still have to throw away the bad input. That is easiest done by calling [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

So, that code should be something like this:

```
double grade;
for (;;) { // loop forever, i.e. until break
    System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
    if (! input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Not a number!");
        input.nextLine(); // discard bad input
        continue; // loop back to try again
    }
    grade = input.nextDouble();
    input.nextLine(); // we only asked for one number, so discard any extra input following the number
    if (grade < 0 || grade > 4.0) {
        System.out.println("Number must be between 0 and 4");
        continue; // loop back to try again
    }
    break; // got good value, so exit loop
}
```